# Imporing large sql file with extended inserts to mysql using PHP?

Tags: php, mysqlimport, large-data

I am having issue when I am trying to import large sql file around 500MB. It has 100,000 extended inserts queries. I have serached every where but nothing found yet.
Bigdump does not support for extended inserts so it is not useful.
And every suggestion that I have seen all fails because all of them have used fopen() or file() which causes MEMORY EXHAUST in PHP even though I have increased the memorty_limit to 512M.
I am looking for a code which can read the sql file of 500MB and go through it and fetch the insert queries which are extended inserts.

Can any one help me in this ???

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this in PHP, running from a webserver.

- if it is a one time operation, use phpmyadmin
- try and see if you can solve this with tools supplied with mysql
- if you have to program (because the file needs to run every day), run PHP in command line mode
- if you do not have access to the command line, try to read parts of the inserts, and process the parts.

Comment: Hi @JvdBerg, thanks for the reply. But I am creating a scripts which I am using for taking a backup of large databases and I want to do it by PHP. So the problem is in reading the parts of inserts because ";\n" may be there in data so I am not able to come with a solution for how to read the specific part until I reach the next insert. I tried fgets(FILE, 4096) but where to stop and start again ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `file()` is that It will read the whole file into a large array. Depending on how big the file is, this can easily hit the memory limit which just happen.

This is not what you usually want. Instead you want to get the lines one by one. This is what `iterators` are perfect for.

I think you should look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php used it to read the file and run it via command line ....